# update choropleth map in d3 v4 using crossfilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, crossfilter, choropleth

I'm using crossfilters in D3 V4 for dimensional charting. I'm also creating a choropleth map, which I want to connect with the crossfilters (i.e. as the crossfilters of the variable Neighborhood change, the choropleth map changes accordingly).

I'm not exactly sure how to update the choropleth. Below is the code I'm using to make a choropleth map. I'm also making a function called map_data(data) that takes the `neighborhoodGroup.all()` key/value pairs and put them on the choropleth. However, I'm not able to call this function in the `update();` function where all the charts are rendered. Any suggestions on how to render/link the choropleth map will be appreciated.

```
  var mapWidth = 550;
  var mapHeight = 550;

 //make a map of Lahore's towns
  var svg = d3.select("#pakistanMap")
  .append('svg') 
  .attr('width', mapWidth)
  .attr('height', mapHeight);

  var g = svg.append("g")

  var crimeById = d3.map(),
      nameById = d3.map();

    var quantize = d3.scaleQuantize()
        .domain([-.02, .05])
        .range(d3.range(9).map(function(i) { return "q" + i + "-9"; }));

  // // D3 Projection
  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
        //.translate([mapWidth/2, mapHeight/2])    // translate to center of screen
        .scale([40000])
       //.
         .center([74.6, 31.5]) // set centre to further North
     //.scale([mapWidth/(2*Math.PI)]) // scale to fit group width
       .translate([465, 250]) // ensure centred in group

    var minimumColor = "#BFD3E6", maximumColor = "#88419D";

    var color = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([2, 10])
    .range([minimumColor, maximumColor]);


    var div = d3.select("#pakistanMap")
    .append("div")   
    .attr("class", "tooltip")               
    .style("opacity", 0);

    d3.json("lahore_towns_geojson2.json", function(err, json) {

    // Loop through each state data value in the crossfilter dimension
      function map_data(data) {


        neighborhood_data = data;
      //console.log(neighborhood_data)
    for (var i = 0; i < neighborhood_data.length; i++) {

      // Grab Neighborhood Name
      var dataNeighborhood = neighborhood_data[i].key;
      // Grab neighborhood crime value 
      var dataValue = neighborhood_data[i].value;

      // Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
      for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++)  {
        var jsonNeighborhood = json.features[j].properties.Name;

        if (dataNeighborhood == jsonNeighborhood) {


        // Copy the data value into the JSON

        json.features[j].properties["visited"] = dataValue; 

        // Stop looking through the JSON
        break;
        }

      }



    };
        return json.features

      };


    // Bind the data to the SVG and create one path per GeoJSON feature
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "map_neighborhood")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(json.features)
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      //.attr("class", function(d) { console.log(quantize(crimeById.get(d[1]))) ; })
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke-width", "0.7")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .on("mouseover", mouseover) 
      .on("mouseout", mouseout)
      .style("fill", function(d, i, data) {
        data = neighborhoodGroup.all()

        all_features = map_data(data);

       var value = d.properties.visited;

      if (value) {
      //If value exists…
      //console.log(color(i))
      return color(i);

      } else {
      //If value is undefined…
      return "rgb(213,222,217)";
      }
    });

});
```

`Update();` function looks like this:

```
 function update() {

  d3.select("#neighborhood-chart")
  .datum(neighborhoodGroup.all())
  .call(myNeighborhoodChart)
  .select(".x.axis")
  .selectAll(".tick text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)");

  svg.selectAll("path")
    .style("fill", function(d, i, data) {

          data = neighborhoodGroup.all()
          // Get data value

         //console.log(data)
         all_features = map_data(data);

         var value = all_features.properties.visited;

          if (value) {
          //If value exists…
          //console.log(color(i))
          return color(i);

          } else {
          //If value is undefined…
          return "rgb(213,222,217)";
          }
        });

  d3.select("#date-chart")
  .datum(dateGroup.all())
  .call(myDateChart);

  d3.select("#hour-chart")
  .datum(hourGroup.all())
  .call(myHourChart);

}
```

The update function, as stated, is returning the error:

```
 map_data() is undefined.
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Try to place your update function in the call back function of d3.json.

Comment: But the update function is not defined at that point, right?

Comment: No it isn't. I mean place the entire body of the function in the call back - map_data's scope is limited to the call back - you can't invoke it outside the callback, even if you could it probably isn't what you want since d3.json is asynchronous.